# Execute a script from a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, go

How to start an external application from a Google Chrome Extension?

I have an executable script written in Go that accepts a URL as a parameter.

I want to be able to execute the script with the current tab's URL as an argument directly from Chrome, without having to start a terminal window, and run my script from there.

I don't mind developing my own Chrome extension, but I am unsure where to start.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [go]? Why not with [javascript]?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - agree, I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome Extension is running on the client side (browser) so it theoretically has to be JavaScript based code.

However, with [GopherJS](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs), I think it's possible to compile Go code into native JS code. There is also an open source binding Go to Chrome extension. https://github.com/fabioberger/chrome

An [example](https://github.com/fabioberger/chrome/tree/master/examples/getting-started-sample) can be found here